# How to divide scattered points among multiple curves?

Tags: classification, clustering, fitting

I have the following scattered points graph:

[image: A scattered points plot]

To me, it seems that the points describe 2 (maybe 3) logarithmic curves. Is there a way to say which point belongs to which curve?